SwiftUI subviews getting clipped inside a scrollview
I've created a Carousel View using a ScrollView and a LazyHStack as follows:
struct CarouselView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    @State private var currentIndex = 0
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    private let showsIndicators: Bool
    private let spacing: CGFloat
    private let shouldSnap: Bool
    
    init(showsIndicators: Bool = true,
         spacing: CGFloat = .zero,
         shouldSnap: Bool = false,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.showsIndicators = showsIndicators
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.shouldSnap = shouldSnap
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: showsIndicators) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: spacing) {
                    content
                }.apply {
                    if #available(iOS 17.0, *), shouldSnap {
                        $0.scrollTargetLayout()
                    } else {
                        $0
                    }
                }
            }
            .clipped() // tried to add this to avoid clipping
            .apply {
                if #available(iOS 17.0, *), shouldSnap {
                    $0.scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                } else {
                    $0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func apply<V: View>(@ViewBuilder _ block: (Self) -> V) -> V { block(self) }
}

I then use it as follows:
struct ContentView: View {
    let imagesNames = ["img-1", "img-2", "img-3", "img-4"]
    let numberOfLines = [2, 1, 3, 2]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            continuousCarousel
        }
        
    }
    
    private var continuousCarousel: some View {
        CarouselView(showsIndicators: true,
                     spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(0 ..< imagesNames.count, id: \.self) { index in
                createImageTile(with: imagesNames[index],
                                height: 70,
                                numberOfLines: numberOfLines[index])
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func createImageTile(with image: String,
                                 height: CGFloat,
                                 numberOfLines: Int) -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .scaledToFit()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
            
            Text("Headline")
                .bold()
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            
            ForEach(0 ..< numberOfLines, id: \.self) { _ in
                Text("Some description here")
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
            }
            
            Spacer() // added to top align content
        }
    }
}

This gives me the result I desire for the most part, however, as you can see, the top of the image gets clipped by the safe area:

I tried to add the clipped modifier to the scrollview as suggested by this answer but to no avail.
How can I solve this ?
Update based on Benzy Neez's 5th idea
This idea of using a hidden footprint almost makes everything work
Just for the example, I store all my titles and supporting text in an array:
let titles = ["Cedele Bakery Kitchen", "Elements Bar and Grill Woolloomooloo", "Osteria di Russo & Russo", "Hopsters Co-op Brewery"]

let supportingText = ["Bangalay Dining, Shoalhaven Heads\n15.5/20", "Modern Australian | Wine bar", "Neptune’s Grotto\n15.5/20.0", "Vegan mapo tofu with shiitake mushrooms and crispy chilli oil\n<30 mins"]

The Carousel implementation does not change that much. One thing to notice is that the last bit of text in the supportingText array is the longest
The only difference is that I have replaced my imageTile with a DemoTile view which has to figure out the right height using the footprint technique:
struct DemoTileView: View {
    
    private let imageName: String
    private let imageWidth: CGFloat
    private let imageHeight: CGFloat
    private let title: String
    private let supportingText: String
    private let allTitles: [String]
    private let allSupportingText: [String]
    
    init(imageName: String,
         title: String,
         allTitles: [String],
         supportingText: String,
         allSupportingText: [String],
         imageWidth: CGFloat,
         imageHeight: CGFloat) {
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.title = title
        self.supportingText = supportingText
        self.allTitles = allTitles
        self.allSupportingText = allSupportingText
        self.imageWidth = imageWidth
        self.imageHeight = imageHeight
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.Border.cornerRadius))
                .padding(.bottom, Constants.Padding.imageBottom)
            
            textViewFootprint
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                    createTextView(title: title, supportingText: supportingText)
                }
            
            Spacer() // added to top align content
        }
        .frame(width: imageWidth)
    }
    
    private var textViewFootprint: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(allTitles.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                let currentTitle = allTitles[index]
                let currentSupportingText = allSupportingText[index]
                createTextView(title: currentTitle, supportingText: currentSupportingText)
            }
        }
        .hidden()
    }
    
    private func createTextView(title: String, supportingText: String) -> some View {
        VStack {
            createTitleView(for: title)
            createSupportingTextView(for: title)
        }
    }
    
    private func createTitleView(for text: String) -> some View {
        // In an HStack to left align the text
        HStack {
            Text(text)
                .bold()
                .padding(.bottom, Constants.Padding.titleBottom)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    private func createSupportingTextView(for text: String) -> some View {
        // In an HStack to left align the text
        HStack {
            Text(supportingText)
                .padding(.bottom, Constants.Padding.supportingTextBottom)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    struct Constants {
        struct Padding {
            static let imageBottom = 12.0
            static let titleBottom = 4.0
            static let supportingTextBottom = 20.0
        }
        
        struct Border {
            static let cornerRadius = 30.0
        }
    }
}

Then within the Carousel, I just do this:
CarouselView(spacing: 10) {
    ForEach(0 ..< imagesNames.count, id: \.self) { index in
        DemoTileView(imageName: imagesNames[index],
                     title: titles[index],
                     allTitles: titles,
                     supportingText: supportingText[index],
                     allSupportingText: supportingText,
                     imageWidth: 180,
                     imageHeight: 120)
        .onTapGesture {
            defaultCarouselIndexTapped = index
        }
    }
}

First two items laid out perfectly

The last item's text get's truncated:

If I give slightly different dimensions like 240 and 170, then this doesn't truncate:


I think you just need to change the modifiers being applied to the Image in the function createImageTile:

You are setting .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill). This is overriding the modifier .scaledToFit() which comes before it, which is therefore redundant.
The modifier .cornerRadius is deprecated, suggest using .clipShape instead.
When scaling-to-fill, a clip shape should be applied after setting the frame size. Setting the clip shape before the frame size would be the way to do it when scaling-to-fit.

BTW, the height parameter being passed to this function is not being used.
So here is an updated version that uses scaled-to-fill. The images are clipped to the containing frame (200x100) using a rounded rectangle.
Image(image)
    .resizable()
//    .cornerRadius(30)
//    .scaledToFit()
//    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
    .padding(.bottom, 30)



EDIT Following from your comments, it sounds like you need to find a way of making sure the LazyHStack reserves enough space to fit the tallest item. You already asked another question about this and marked an answer as accepted, so I would have expected, you found a solution already. However, if it's still an issue then some techniques you could try are:

Set a minimum height on the carousel:

continuousCarousel
    .frame(minHeight: 300, alignment: .top) //  ADDED


Allow the text to shrink to fit:

ForEach(0 ..< imagesNames.count, id: \.self) { index in
    createImageTile(
        // ...
    )
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1) //  ADDED


Reserve enough space for the maximum number of text lines

Text("Some description here")
    .lineLimit(3, reservesSpace: true) //  ADDED
    .padding(.bottom, 5)


Use hidden content to reserve space:

ForEach(0 ..< numberOfLines, id: \.self) { _ in
    Text("Some description here")
        .padding(.bottom, 5)
}
ForEach(0 ..< (3-numberOfLines), id: \.self) { _ in //  BLOCK ADDED
    Text("Hidden")
        .padding(.bottom, 5)
        .hidden()
}


Use a hidden placeholder to establish the footprint for the text, then show the actual content as an overlay:

VStack(spacing: .zero) {
    Image(image)
        // ...

    textFootprint //  PLACEHOLDER (implement separately)
        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Headline")
                    // ...
                ForEach(0 ..< numberOfLines, id: \.self) { _ in
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    Spacer() // added to top align content
}


Thanks. This does work for the most part, however, the third item with 4 lines of still gets clipped, however, it seems to be pushed out of bounds: https://prnt.sc/wz4RugFRXu-Y - This can be overcome by using an HStack instead of a LazyHStack but preference is to use a LazyHStack for the performance.

Did you scroll to the third item ? Thats the one where this happens. I put all this code in isolation and applied your changes. The clipping works fine for all except the one with max lines. I do not apply any sizing to the carousel view, the only size that is applied is to the image. I notice that if the first item is the one with max height, then the carousel is sized properly. Probably because LazyHStack doesn't know there will be a larger object later and so we have this issue. Also the last 2 modifiers you mention, what would I apply this to ?

Thank you for some options, I will give it a try. I was wondering if it was possible to do something like create all the tile views to figure out the max height required and only then create the carousel and set the min height of the carousel to be the max height all the tiles / items ?

Thank you for helping me so far. Idea 5 with your suggestions almost works for me. I've updated my question with what I've implemented based on your idea, the issue right now is that the text seems to truncate at some moments.

so this does fix the text and it is no longer truncated, however now the it seems the tile is pushed out of bounds and the image now truncated / forced out of bounds similar to the original problem we had but just for this specific tile / item.

@ShawnFrank I would be tempted to get rid of all the spacers. Instead, try using .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) for enforcing left justification and .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top) for top justification (where actually needed).

Well I was able to do the alignment using your above methods so it's a great refactor, however, the truncation exists. Happy to make that a seperate question if you feel it warrants it.

New question is here if you have any other ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78423436/text-getting-truncated-in-carousel-using-scrollview-and-lazyhstack
